# React getting index.html response instead of API data from GET/POST methods after deploying to IIS v10

Tags: reactjs, api, iis, http-proxy-middleware

I'm following the instruction on how to build react app in the IIS. [URL](https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied)
However, for some reason, all my API calls are getting 404 errors.
Any hints or advice would be appreciated!

I'm using a proxy in order to bypass CORS policy on specific URLs.
Whenever I'm running using the terminal/code editor the API works perfectly, the response API errors only happen after I've deployed to the IIS.

Here are my codes:

Proxy i 've set:

```
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require("http-proxy-middleware");

  module.exports = function(app) {
   app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware('/v3/quotes',{
            target:'https://quote.dellsvc',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true         
        })
    );
```

web.config for react routes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
<cors enabled="true">
    <add origin="*" >
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
    </add>
</cors>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Terminal:- network request and console result:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/v3/quotes?number=xxx&version=x
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Data response:
Able to retrieve the data correctly.
[image: Data response]

After deploying to IIS:- network request and console result:

```
Request URL: http://11.111.111.111:8000/v3/quotes?number=xxx&version=x
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.139.140.218:8000
```

Data response:
It shows the data of index.html instead of the API response data.
[image: Data Response]

**Note:** The data is able to retrieve even though it has been deployed to IIS if without setting up a proxy (For example the API that is able to retrieve without the blockage from the CORS policy)

Comment: You proxy rules on `v3/quotes` only take effect during development on the dev server. When deploying to IIS you need extra configuration, such as some rewrite rules with IIS URL Rewrite module.

Comment: Bypassing the CORS policy does not necessarily require a proxy. The CORS module of IIS allows you to accept non-same-origin requests after setting, so that you can get data.

Comment: Thank you all! I'm very new to react and even new to deploying into the IIS server. For some reason, I'm still unable to bypass the CORS although follow this [CORS URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-configuration) by setting up the CORS module in the react web.config. any suggestions guys? this is a very last step and I would really appreciate it if you can help!

Comment: I've just updated my latest web.config file above. I've installed the IIS CORS Module as well by following the instructions.

Comment: What's the error browser reported when request the domain?